# The Android App Bundle was not signed even after changing debug mode to release mode

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
 if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
   localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
 }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the        local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

 def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
 if (flutterVersionName == null) {
 flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 29

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.example"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
 }
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

}
}

flutter {
 source '../..'
}

dependencies {
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
  implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
  implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16'
```

}

This is my app/build.gradle file
I have generated a jks file for release mode. I have also set the release config as release. But still, when I try to upload my app on google play store, "The Android App Bundle was not signed." error comes.
I have also tried flutter clean many times, but nothing is working. Please help!

Comment: This question probably cannot be answered, because it's unknown what `keystoreProperties` is. Likely `key.properties` has no release key-store defined or the wrong password to it.

Comment: key.properties has a storeFile where key.jks file exists. I tried putting incorrect password to check whether the file really exists or not, and it says that password is incorrect.

Comment: I changed the google - json file in the current version of the app. Does it have to do anything with the key file? Because, the key file definitely exists as I have already uploaded one version of the app using it.